# trying to display my variable value but output is null

Tags: android, flutter

I'm doing a project in Flutter in which I'm getting live bit rate using a API and I'm getting my rate but can't display on my screen its say it null..! code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'coin_data.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
import 'networking.dart';

class PriceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PriceScreenState createState() => _PriceScreenState();
}

class _PriceScreenState extends State<PriceScreen> {
  BitNetwork bitNetwork = BitNetwork('$BitCoinURL/BTC/USD?apikey=$BitCoinKey');
  int bitRate;

  void getCurrentBitRate() async {
    dynamic bitData = await bitNetwork.getData();
    double temp = bitData['rate'];
    bitRate = temp.toInt();
    print(bitRate);
  }

  String selectedCurrency = 'USD';`enter code here`

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getCurrentBitRate();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Coin Ticker'),
      ),`enter code here`
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 0),
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              elevation: 5.0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 28.0),
                child: Text(
                  '1 BTC = $bitRate USD',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
              height: 150.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              child: Platform.isIOS ? iOSPicker() : androidDropdown()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

answer in console:
I/flutter (14181): 47131
I/flutter (14181): 47131
I/flutter (14181): 47129

output on screen is = 1 BTC = null USD. => ????

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for currency loading, wrap your widget to `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
Future<int> getCurrentBitRate() async {
  dynamic bitData = await bitNetwork.getData();
  double temp = bitData['rate'];
  return temp.toInt();
}

// build method
child: FutureBuilder<int>(
  future: getCurrentBitRate(),
  builder (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final bitRate = snapshot.data;
      return Column(
        // Your column here.
      );
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
),
```

Also, you can find more information about how to work with async features [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) and read more about `FutureBuilder` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not awaiting getCurrentBitRate() and you are also calling it in your build method.  Only UI code should be in the build method.  What I recommend you do is override initState() and call it in there (Still can't await it, but it will be called before build);

```
@override
initState(){
  getCurrentBitRate();
  super.initState();
}
```

This will help with your issue, but it's not the best solution.  I recommend looking up tutorials on some external state management system, such as BLoC, Provider and/or RxDart.  This will make situations like this much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

It's null because when `build()` is called, `getCurrentBitRate()` didn't complete it's job yet.

For those operations `FutureBuilder` is one of the best widget. It just needs a `future`, and a `builder` to declare what to do after the data received.

```
// CHANGE TO FUTURE STYLE
Future<Int> getCurrentBitRate() async {
  dynamic bitData = await bitNetwork.getData();
  double temp = bitData['rate'];
  bitRate = temp.toInt();
  print(bitRate);
  return bitRate;
}
```

Then change build structure to this

```
 // DECLARE A FUTURE FOR getCurrentBitRate()
 Future _future;

 initState(){
   _future = await getCurrentBitRate();
   super.initState();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // getCurrentBitRate(); REMOVE THIS LINE
   return FutureBuilder(
     future: _future,
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if(snapshot.hasData){

         // YOUR DATA IS READY
         double temp = snapshot.data['rate'];
         
         // JUST CONTINUE REST OF ORIGINAL CODE BELOW 
         return Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text('Coin Ticker'),
           ),
           ...
       }
     }
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `bitRate` value is `null` because you are calling it in `build` function & your method `getCurrentBitRate()` is an `async` method, which means that the method will wait to get the value but till then your `build` method would already finish rendering the widgets with `bitRate` value still `null`.

There are multiple ways to fix this but the one I would recommend is as follows:

Call your method `getCurrentBitRate()` in `initState` method & remove it from the `build` function as it is the first method that runs in your widget & use `setState` so that updated value of `bitRate` is shown in your widget.

```
class _PriceScreenState extends State<PriceScreen> {
  BitNetwork bitNetwork = BitNetwork('$BitCoinURL/BTC/USD?apikey=$BitCoinKey');
  int bitRate;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getCurrentBitRate(); // Call it in initState & use setState
  }

  void getCurrentBitRate() async {
    dynamic bitData = await bitNetwork.getData();
    double temp = bitData['rate'];
    bitRate = temp.toInt();
    print(bitRate);
    if (mounted) {  // <--- mounted property checks whether your widget is still present in the widget tree
      setState((){}); // Will update the UI once the value is retrieved
    }
  }

  String selectedCurrency = 'USD';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Coin Ticker'),
      ),`enter code here`
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 0),
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              elevation: 5.0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 28.0),
                child: Text(
                  '1 BTC = $bitRate USD',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
              height: 150.0,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              child: Platform.isIOS ? iOSPicker() : androidDropdown()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```